# Disable "Ask where to save each file before downloading" for one extension

Tags: google-chrome, download, google-chrome-extensions, download-manager

My university has a Google Chrome extension to download notes from the portal. It allows us to download everything a professor has uploaded and automatically organises it in the OS file system. There are often 100s of documents, so this bulk organization system is really useful.

The Chrome Webstore page of the extension states that we should disable the setting "Ask where to save each file before downloading", which is reasonable because I shouldn't have to click on a dialog box several times.

However, I would like to leave that setting enabled globally (because I rely on it to protect me from random malicious downloads) and disable it just for the relevant extension. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: A workaround: set up a second profile, just for downloaded course material, and log into the other profile most of the time: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform=Desktop

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Yeah, this is what I'm currently doing